# Cannot Use Count Variable in Embedded Array Lookup

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, scope

I'm quite fluent in C# but am struggling on a very basic (it seems) concept here in the javascript portion of my ticket. This piece of code:

```
addPaymentsToBreakdown = function () {
    for (var count = 0; count < checkedPayments.length; count++) {
        (function (count) {
            console.log(checkedPayments[0][count].value); 
        })(count); 
    }
}
```

Is a smaller portion of a larger function that I have written. The array 'checkedPayments' is being used elsewhere and is properly instantiated.

The concept that I am failing to understand is why I can't simply use the count variable in my function to iterate over the second tier of 'count' indexes in the array. If I manually were to put in a number there I could look up any of the indexes fine. I can also just console.log() every element in the array, but for some reason the combination of using that count variable with the embedded array index is messing things up. The error that
 I see after is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of   undefined.` Please help me with a fix, and a simple explanation as to why things aren't working. Thanks

Comment: Is `checkedPayments[0]` an array of the same length as `checkedPayments.length`?

Comment: You may use `let` instead of `var`. But with `var` you may do like `(function (i) { return console.log(checkedPayments[0][i].value); })(count)` Don't use `count` as inner functions argument.

Comment: Your code works unmodified in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hvqcLoff/1/), although the structure of checkedPayments strikes me as odd.

Comment: Can you explain why you're iterating on `checkedPayments.length` but then accessing `checkedPayments[0][count]` as opposed to `checkedPayments[count]`?

Comment: @ray Thanks everyone for the comments: The reason that the array looks a little strange is because the array is being filled after having pulled elements off the page from a combobox that contains checkable elements for the user. When this array is filled, the elements are objects. Thus making this array an array of objects. That is why there is an embedded structure. I need to access the 'value' attribute of these objects and the hierarchy of that data is array -- > array --> value

Comment: If it's an array of objects you'd want to access `checkedPayments[count].value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your guys feedback. I ended up finding the answer and I would like to share it. The code : `addPaymentsToBreakdown = function () {
        console.log('checkedPayments:', checkedPayments); 
        for (var count = 0; count < checkedPayments.length; count++) {
            console.log(checkedPayments[count][0].value);
        }
    }`

Ended up doing exactly what I needed. The key was in finding the [count][0].value. I needed to access one layer down further than I was. The output of this array now displays the value of the three elements, which represent ID's from the database. I can now use this to complete my query. Thanks for your help ;)